# How to use python asyncio to asynchronously dispatch tasks?

Tags: python, python-asyncio, p2p

I am looking to implement a simple p2p file downloader in python. The downloader needs to work within the following limitations:

- When queried, the tracker responds with exactly 2 peers
- The tracker ignores requests made within 2 seconds of the previous request

The downloader should attempt to download a single file as fast as possible. From my reading about this I thought that I should be using asyncio. I thought I'd structure the code something like this pseudo code:

```
async def downloader(peer):
    while file is not downloaded:
        download a new block from the peer without blocking

response = synchronously query tracker for initial pair of peers
newPeers = exractPeers(response)
while file not downloaded:
    for peer in newPeers:
        dispatch new downloader(peer)
    wait 2 seconds without blocking downloaders
    response = query tracker for initial pair of peers without blocking downloaders
    newPeers = exractPeers(response)
```

What asyncio methods should I be using to "dispatch" new downloaders and query the tracker? From my testing it seems that `await`ing an async function blocks the event loop:

```
import asyncio
from random import randint

async def myfunc(i):
    print("hello", i)
    await asyncio.sleep(randint(1,3))
    print("world", i)

async def main():
    await myfunc(1)
    await myfunc(2)
    await myfunc(3)
    await myfunc(4)
    
asyncio.run(main())
```

This code runs each `myfunc` call as though it were defined without `async`. I'd appreciate anything, including basic pointers.

Comment: You can check [Coroutines and Tasks](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html).

Comment: To put it simply, `await myfunc()` only suspends the execution inside the `main()` function. It does not "block" the entire asyncio loop. If you want to await several things at the same time, check out `asyncio.gather` and `asyncio.wait`.

Comment: @MMM If I acquire more tasks over time (i.e. every 2 seconds I get 2 new peers I can communicate with) would gather/wait be the right methods to use? From what I'm understanding the group is blocked as a whole, but the downloaders will run forever (until the file is completely downloaded)

Comment: @CodeM4aster, gather and wait don't support adding new tasks inside them. You might wanna try spawning tasks via `asyncio.create_task()`. After calling this method your task will be scheduled to run and you don't have to await it.